# how to lint sieve scripts in a programmatic way

Tags: sieve

how can I lint sieve scripts in a programmatic way?

I am looking for something to integrate in a sieve editor

I have not found any reference in the sieve documentation

Answer (score 2):

With pigeonhole, that is dovecot sieve you can use `sievec` and test the return value to be non-zero for failure.

Comment: first of all thank you, but my problem is I am looking for some source code of just the linter. I am working on a sieve editor to use outside a dovecot server installation.